# MouseUp Event doesn't run after MouseDown

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseup

Trying to build a scrollbar that when you click and hold the mouse button and start to move along the Y-axis it is going to move the site up or down with some sensitivity. Everything is working fine, scrolling is smooth and works exactly I wanted. The problem is, that when you stop to hold the mouse button, it is still moving the site up and down on mouse move.

My Code

```js
scrollbar.addEventListener("mousedown", scrollWhenMove);
body.addEventListener("mouseup", stopScroll);
function scrollWhenMove()
{
    scrollbar.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {onmove(event)})
    function onmove(event)
    {
        var moved = event.movementY;
        if(moved !== 0)
        {
            document.documentElement.scrollTop += (moved * 3);
        }
    }
}
function stopScroll()
{
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        return false;
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: The first problem is that you `addEventListener('mousemove', ...)`, but you never `removeEventListener('mousemove', ...)`. There are other mistakes (`function() {onmove(event)}` where `event` is `undefined`, and the fact that you cannot `removeEventListener` of an anonymous handler, and the fact that you scroll back to the top on mouse up...)

Comment: Doesn't run as in it doesn't enter the stopScroll() function? or that it's literally not detecting the event? BTW, shouldn't you be adding the mouseup event to the scroll bar as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `removeEventListener` to stop listening to mouse move when `stopScroll` is called.

However, note that it will only work if you pass it the same reference to the function that was passed in the previous `addEventListener`:

```
// 2 different anonymous functions won't work
scrollbar.addEventListener("mousemove", function() { onmove(); });
scrollbar.removeEventListener("mousemove", function() { onmove(); });

// OK, same reference
scrollbar.addEventListener("mousemove", onmove);
scrollbar.removeEventListener("mousemove", onmove);
```

Demo:

```js
scrollbar.addEventListener("mousedown", scrollWhenMove);
document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", stopScroll);

function scrollWhenMove() {
  scrollbar.addEventListener("mousemove", onmove);
}

function stopScroll() {
  scrollbar.removeEventListener("mousemove", onmove);
}

function onmove(event) {
  var moved = event.movementY;
  if (moved !== 0) {
    document.documentElement.scrollTop += (moved * 3);
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 90%;
}

#scrollbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://wvs.topleftpixel.com/photos/scotia_plaza_tall_stitched.jpg">

<div id="scrollbar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour is stopping the mouseMove and mouseUp from running, you can solve this by basically adding event.preventDefault() to the mousedown function

please ensure that you use the same parameter name passed in the mousedown function to trigger the preventDefault() if not it will not work , in the example below i passed event as the parameter to the mousedown function and then triggered preventDefault() by typing event.preventDefault()

```
 let mousePosStart, isDown = false;

 function mousedown(event) {
        if (isDown == false) {
            mousePosStart = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            isDown = true;
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    function mousemove(event) {
        if (isDown == true) {
            let mousePosMove = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        }
    }

    function mouseup(event) {
        if (isDown === true) {
            isDown = false;
            let mousePosEnd = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        }
    }
```